# My props are passed down to my component but I can't figure out the right path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am making a small recipe app and when I do my axios get request, I see that I am passing down the props to my SearchResults component, but when I try to access props.results. whatever I am trying to get, I keep getting back undefined.

Here I am mapping through the results and passing them to my SearchResults component

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
   const axios = require('axios');

    function GrillApi() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

    function apiSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/list',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'tasty.p.rapidapi.com',
                'x-rapidapi-key':
                    'mykey',
                useQueryString: true,
            },
            params: {
                q: `${search}`,
                from: '0',
                sizes: '20',
            },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.results);
                setApiData(response.data.results);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    const results = apiData.map((results) => (
        <SearchResults key={results.id} results={results} />
    ));
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={apiSearch}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="search"
                    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button>search</button>
            </form>
            {results}
        </div>
    );
}
export default GrillApi;
```

```
import React from 'react';

function SearchResults(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return <div><h2>{props.results.name}</h2></div>;
}
export default SearchResults;
```

```
{results: {…}}
results:
approved_at: 1600262844
aspect_ratio: null
beauty_url: null
brand: {slug: "guinness", image_url: "https://img.buzzfeed.com/tasty-app-user-assets-pro…t-1/recipes/513b33f218e7486cbbe978c8bd53560d.jpeg", id: 32, name: "Guinness"}
brand_id: 32
buzz_id: null
canonical_id: "recipe:6573"
compilations: []
cook_time_minutes: null
country: "US"
created_at: 1600204703
credits: [{…}]
description: ""
draft_status: "published"
facebook_posts: []
id: 6573
inspired_by_url: null
instructions: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
is_one_top: false
is_shoppable: false
keywords: ""
language: "eng"
name: "Guinness Short Rib Chili"
num_servings: 4
nutrition: {calories: 1034, carbohydrates: 99, fat: 39, protein: 56, sugar: 18, …}
nutrition_visibility: "auto"
original_video_url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/video-api-prod/assets/ad65a0aaf74c423aad22769324cad447/DIAGEO_Guinness_BeerChili_FB.mp4"
prep_time_minutes: null
promotion: "full"
renditions: []
sections: (2) [{…}, {…}]
seo_title: ""
servings_noun_plural: "servings"
servings_noun_singular: "serving"
show: {id: 17, name: "Tasty"}
show_id: 17
slug: "guinness-short-rib-chili"
tags: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
thumbnail_url: "https://img.buzzfeed.com/thumbnailer-prod-us-east-1/video-api/assets/283083.jpg"
tips_and_ratings_enabled: true
total_time_minutes: null
total_time_tier: null
updated_at: 1600262845
user_ratings: {count_positive: 0, count_negative: 0, score: null}
video_ad_content: "co_branded"
video_id: 112098
video_url: null
yields: "Servings: 4"
__proto__: Object
key: (...)
get key: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

I am pretty sure I am calling the right thing after results.. Is there a sure way that I am pointing to the right path in the api call?

Thanks for any help!

## WORKING CODE

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
   const axios = require('axios');

    function GrillApi() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

    function apiSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/list',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'tasty.p.rapidapi.com',
                'x-rapidapi-key':
                    'mykey',
                useQueryString: true,
            },
            params: {
                q: `${search}`,
                from: '0',
                sizes: '20',
            },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.results);
                setApiData(response.data.results);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

## I am going to have to get each object idividualy and pass them ##

    const results = apiData.map((results) => (
        <SearchResults key={results.id} name={results.name} />
    ));

## name={results.name} ##    

return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={apiSearch}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="search"
                    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button>search</button>
            </form>
            {results}
        </div>
    );
}
export default GrillApi;
```

Comment: Try creating a sandbox here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uhzb18

Comment: Or, can you post the values of `response.data.results` in your question?

Comment: just added the results..  never made a sandbox but will try as well.  Thanks

Comment: What about changing `function SearchResults(props) {}` to  `const SearchResults = props => {}`

Comment: @RaphaelM. Doesn't matter. More or less, using both doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: `results` from the API response appears to be an object, not an array.

Comment: @BrianThompson ahh okay,  so what would be the best way to pass those as props or how could I access them?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,  thanks for all the help. I had to get each object individually and pass it over as a param instead of the whole result which was returning an object

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
   const axios = require('axios');

    function GrillApi() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

    function apiSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/list',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'tasty.p.rapidapi.com',
                'x-rapidapi-key':
                    'mykey',
                useQueryString: true,
            },
            params: {
                q: `${search}`,
                from: '0',
                sizes: '20',
            },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.results);
                setApiData(response.data.results);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

## I am going to have to get each object idividualy and pass them ##

    const results = apiData.map((results) => (
        <SearchResults key={results.id} name={results.name} />
    ));

## name={results.name} ##    

return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={apiSearch}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="search"
                    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button>search</button>
            </form>
            {results}
        </div>
    );
}
export default GrillApi;
```

Comment: Please post the answer as the answer instead of editing the question.